# How to add JDBC driver to Flyway Gradle plugin

Tags: jdbc, gradle, flyway, gradle-plugin

I am using Gradle 3.0 and I would like to add Flyway tasks to my project build file.

I added the following to build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id "org.flywaydb.flyway" version "4.0.3"
}
```

When running gradle flywayInfo I got the following error:
Execution failed for task ':common:flywayInfo'.

> Error occurred while executing flywayInfo
>   Unable to instantiate JDBC driver: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

In a standalone Flyway installation, I can copy additional driver jar files into drivers folder so that Flyway can use that driver. How can I achieve the same thing with the plugin?

I have tried to add dependency to the build file but it does not help.

```
buildscript {
  dependencies {
    files("lib/ojdbc7.jar")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be

```
buildscript {
   dependencies {
      classpath files("lib/ojdbc7.jar")
   }
}
```